# sql: Scan error on column index 6, name "scheduled_date": null: cannot scan type []uint8 into null.Time

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

I get this error and tried everything available in the internet and stackoverlow to solve this. I am trying to run a query after connecting MySQL db using sqlx package and scan through the results. I have tried the solutions shared for similar questions but nothing worked for me.

```
type Trip struct {
    ID                 int       `db:"id"`
    Type           int       `db:"type"`
    DID           int       `db:"did"`
    DUID       int       `db:"duid"`
    VID          int       `db:"vid"`
    Sts             string    `db:"sts"`
    AM      int       `db:"am"`
    Sdate null.Time `db:"sdate"`
}


func GetTripByID(db sqlx.Queryer, id int) (*Trip, error) {
    row := db.QueryRowx("select ID,Type,DID,DUID,VID,Sts,AM,Sdate from mytbl where ID=123", id)
    var t Trip
    err := row.StructScan(&t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error during struct scan")
        return nil, err
    }
    return &t, nil
}
```

The exact error that I get is

> panic: sql: Scan error on column index 6, name "sdate": null:
>   cannot scan type []uint8 into null.Time: [50 48 49 56 45 49 50 45 48
>   55 32 48 50 58 48 56 58 53 49]

syntax wise the query is working perfectly fine and I am getting results when I run it in sql workbench. I have also tried ParseTime=true as suggested by one of the one of the links.

Comment: Please [`gofmt`](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) your code

Comment: Where is `null.Time` coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use special types for null values in package "database/sql"

For example, when text or varchar can be null in db, use sql.NullString for var type.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, I did null handling for the column "Sdate"

```
// NullTime defining nullTime
type NullTime mysql.NullTime

// Scan implements the Scanner interface for NullTime
func (nt *NullTime) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    var t mysql.NullTime
    if err := t.Scan(value); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // if nil then make Valid false
    if reflect.TypeOf(value) == nil {
        *nt = NullTime{t.Time, false}
    } else {
        *nt = NullTime{t.Time, true}
    }
```

and changes in the struct

```
type Trip struct {
    ID                 int       `db:"id"`
    Type           int       `db:"type"`
    DID           int       `db:"did"`
    DUID       int       `db:"duid"`
    VID          int       `db:"vid"`
    Sts             string    `db:"sts"`
    AM      int       `db:"am"`
    Sdate NullTime `db:"sdate"`
}
```

so the solution is not just defining the struct for handling null but also implementing the scanner interface.